# Concatenate two properties inline in select-object

Tags: powershell

I have an object array like

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Name: Name1,
  Users: 
  [
     {
       Identifier: a@a.com,
       AccessRight: Admin
     },
     {
       Identifier: b@b.com,
       AccessRight: Member
     }
  ]
},
{
  Id: 2,
  Name: Name2,
  Users: 
  [
     {
       Identifier: c@c.com,
       AccessRight: Admin
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to produce the following csv output

| Id | Name | Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | a@a.com;Admin,b@b.com;Member |
| 2 | Name2 | c@c.com;Admin |

I'm failing on concatenating the Users...

```
$users | Select Id, Name, @{Name="Users";Expression={ $_.Users.Identifier -join "," }}
```

produces:

| Id | Name | Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | a@a.com,b@b.com |
| 2 | Name2 | c@c.com |

How can I concatenate the `Identifier` + `AccessRight` with semicolon part before joining with commas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your property expression to iterate over each object in `Users` and concatenate the two relevant sub-properties before you `-join` (again):

```
 $users | Select Id, Name, @{Name="Users";Expression={ $_.Users.ForEach({$_.Identifier,$_.AccessRight -join ';'}) -join "," }}
```